# What is the best way to share runtime data between docker containers with nodejs ? (Not volume)

Tags: node.js, docker, sockets, docker-compose, microservices

I need to share runtime data between containers.
example:

I am using two containers one application and one notification. I need to pass data from application container to notification container.

Approaches I know so far:

1. TCP connection
2. Sockets

Answer (score 1):

Use 3rd container with [redis](https://redis.io/) database in it.

1. There are few good nodejs drivers for redis.
2. Redis can be shared cache/key-value database/counters/queues - depends on data structure you use and for what.
3. You can use [publish/subscribe](https://redis.io/commands#pubsub) commands to send notifications from app to notification handler container